# Frobenius norm minimization using MATLAB and CVX

Tags: matlab, optimization, matrix, libsvm, cvx

I have a SVM problem of the form:

```
minimize ||Q||_F subject to l_i (x_i^T Q x_i) >= 1
```

where `Q` is a square matrix, the `x_i`'s are the training examples and the `l_i`'s are the labels for the training examples.

Is there a way to solve this using existing optimization tools for MATLAB using a built-in optimization routine or CVX, libsvm or other optimization package?

Comment: I'm afraid this question is not a good fit for Stack Overflow. First, it's probably unclear for most programmers around. Then, it's either too broad (if you'd want us to write the code) or a library/tool recommendation question (which is also off-topic as it tends to attract spammy and low-quality answers.

Answer (score 0):

Exploiting properties of the trace operator, we obtain the following

[image]

which should be easy to translate to CVX. Squaring the norm and vectorizing the matrix, we obtain an inequality-constrained quadratic program. Instead of using CVX, one can also use [quadprog](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/quadprog.html).

---

LaTeX code:

```
$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \| \mathrm Q \|_F\\ \text{subject to} & \mbox{tr} (l_1  \mathrm x_1  \mathrm x_1^T  \mathrm Q) \geq 1\\ &\qquad\vdots\\ & \mbox{tr} (l_m  \mathrm x_m  \mathrm x_m^T  \mathrm Q) \geq 1\end{array}$$
```